# number 3 but some apps show sign =

Tags: sql, windows, formatting

When I tried to run a SQLQuery, I get the row affected message

For example, if I have 3 rows in my database, it should show `3 rows affected`

But my computer shows `= rows affected`

Are there any ways for me to change the format of the number in Windows? (I think so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server then try this-

```
Select @@ROWCOUNT
```

It returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. If the number of rows is more than 2 billion, use ROWCOUNT_BIG.

Comment: I mean I know to use that function, but the thing is that it was a like a number format problem for the whole system i guess because on other application, I also shows characters instead of numbers. What I mean is that whenever i see a number like `3 4 5`, it supposed to show like that right? but it shows `= 4 =`. When I try to type in the search bar the code but shows the original number. I am just clueless

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that is just a font error. I installed a modded font for another app and I figured out it might be the problem. Just uninstall the font then restart your computer